# yii mssql cannot update identity column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, yii

yii 1.1.13,
MS SQL Server 2012

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[name](
   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Model, contoller and CRUD created via gii.

_form.php:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'name-form',));
echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50));
echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save');
$this->endWidget();
```

When

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Name'];
$model->save();
```

> General error: 20018 Cannot update identity column 'id'. [20018] (severity 5)

Temporary solution is:
`unset($model->id)`, but it's not clear.

What solution is nice?

Answer (score 0):

Yii make's SQL:

```
UPDATE [name] SET [id]=:yp0,
[name]=:yp1 WHERE [name].[id]=2
```

My _form.php have not field 'id'. Why yii set

> [id]=:yp0

?